# taking ownership of uxtheme.dll in c++ and win 8.1

Tags: c++, installation, ownership, trusted, uxtheme

Im trying to get ownership of the uxtheme.dll in my windows 8.1 system32 folder programatically (c++). I read, tried and googled for several hours now but cant find any solution. Every time the uxtheme ownership is set, it doesnt show up in the properties tab. Ownership and full rights are always inherited by the Trusted Installer.

I tried it with `system("takeown /f C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll")` which prints out success but sadly is not working.

Same goes for the function `TakeOwnership()` from msdn. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx]

What do i need to do, to inherit ownership for the local admin, so i can switch out this dll? Does resource protection have anything to do with it?

Once the ownership is set will i be able to replace the dll with MoveFileEx()?

thank you very much,
lody

Comment: When you use the `system` function it creates a *new* process for the command, which is why it will not work.

Comment: As for the `TakeOwnership` function, as with any other system function, you need to check *why* it fails. This is done with the [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (note: only call if a function actually failed). See [here for a list of error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your quick awnser! So should i use WinExec() or ShellEexecute() instead? As i said it doesnt fail. It quits with message "DACL changed sucessful".

Comment: I just got a step further. 
I had to set ownership of \windows\ and \system32\ folders first before i could set the ownership for the file.

Best regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved my problem.

Take ownership of all directorys the file is in.
Be aware: If youre running 64bit, pathes to system\ files will be redirected to SysWoW64\ folder.